# How to align the card image to centre in Plotly Dash Bootstrap Component?

Tags: plotly-dash, plotly-python

Is there a way to align the dbc.card image to center in Plotly Dash Bootstrap? I have gone through the documentation and I could find only "Top" and "Bottom". Thanks. Below is the code snippet:

```
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import dash_html_components as HTML
card = dbc.Card(
[
    dbc.CardImg(src="/static/images/placeholder286x180.png", top=True),
    dbc.CardBody(
        [
            html.H4("Card title", className="card-title"),
            html.P(
                "Some quick example text to build on the card title and "
                "make up the bulk of the card's content.",
                className="card-text",
            ),
            dbc.Button("Go somewhere", color="primary"),
        ]
    ),
],
style={"width": "18rem"},)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Needed to solve the same question, this is what I found using [Bootstrap cheatsheet](https://hackerthemes.com/bootstrap-cheatsheet/):

```
dbc.CardImg(src="/static/images/placeholder286x180.png", className = 'align-self-center')
```

I'm new to this so it might not be the most correct, but it worked for me.